# Datepicker Angular2 Hidden Popup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue about using multiple datepicer at one page in angular2 
this is example code 
https://embed.plnkr.co/nRCpS4/

the problem is, i want to hide datepicker popup when i click another datepicker

Can someone please help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified `openDatePicker` method a bit:

```
  openDatepicker(id){
    if (this.dynamicId && this.dynamicId !== id) {
      this.dynamicId.close();
    }
    this.dynamicId = id;
  }
```

About `onClick` that should hide datepicker when clicked somewhere on the page excluding current input and datepicker button I've used this condition:

```
if (!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target) || !this.dynamicId._elRef.nativeElement.parentNode.contains(event.target)) {
      setTimeout(() => this.dynamicId.close(), 10);
    }
```

It relies that input and button have common parent, otherwise it won't work.

plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ziTk5B4x8sFiTPXMc52Y

Comment: got it, thanks you so much.
i have a question again, how to hide datepicker when i click the another input bar?

Comment: help me with the onClick function

Comment: About this... In general I would create component that wraps one date picker and your code would be fine. However I used something more complicated and less reliable in the example...

Comment: If i create component for wrap datepicker, thats mean if i have 4 datepicker form in one page i need to create 4 component ? is that normal on angular ? i just learn angular in a few day

Comment: No, I mean 1 component that extends the functionality of datepicker provided by the library. As you can see your datepickers have the same html structure, so it doesn't have to be repeated. There are actually 2 things that differ between them here - name and ngModel - both can be passed as a component parameters. Example wrapper for datepicker can look like this: `<datepicker name="injectedName" [(ngModel)]="variable_that_will_be_passed_lower_on_input"></datepicker>`. I think this is something for another question ;)

Comment: Can i create new question post for that and please give me example on plunker for thats case ? :)

Comment: Sure, just mention me there. I'll probably respond on it later, 7 am is a good time for some sleep ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004293/multiple-datepicker-in-one-form-angular2-with-difference-component this is new question